# Grouping and colouring with ggplot at the same time

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

I've got two teams and a given value for each team and year for a certain time interval. My data looks like the following:

| yearID | teamID | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 0 | 5 |
| 2020 | 1 | 7 |
| 2019 | 0 | 3 |
| 2019 | 1 | 1 |

I want to plot this with a point for each year and value, distunguishing between teams by color.
Additionally I want to draw lines between points grouped by year. I am almost there:

`ggplot(hr_by_team_year_sf_la_df, aes(x='yearID', y='HR', group='yearID')) + geom_line() + geom_point()`

resulting in the following plot:

[image]

Only colors miss for now. I've tried several approaches but none succeeded:

1. `ggplot(hr_by_team_year_sf_la_df, aes(x='yearID', y='HR', group='yearID')) + geom_line() + geom_point(aes(color='teamID'))`
2. `ggplot(hr_by_team_year_sf_la_df, aes(x='yearID', y='HR', group='yearID', color='teamID')) + geom_line() + geom_point()`

**Anyone got an idea how to paint the points depending on the teamId?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(yearID = c("2020","2020","2019","2019"), 
             teamID = c(0, 1, 0, 1), 
             value = c(5, 7, 3, 1)) %>% 
  mutate(teamID = as.factor(teamID))

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_line(aes(yearID, value)) + 
  geom_point(aes(yearID, value, color = teamID), size = 3)
```

[image]